# How to fix Cordova signing issue?

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

Currently I have app that is on google play, I have keystore and the password. When I try to build my app using  `cordova build android` I works fine, got the unsigned apk. but when i try to sign `cordova build android --release` the app it shows me an error. the out put looks like below, can you help me to fix this ?

---

```
(node:15200) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
```

Android Studio project detected

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_c21n0taxk7sttbckav1bwd5za.run(C:\Users\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:144)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script \platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 147
- What went wrong:
  Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException

  > java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 147
- What went wrong:
  Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException

  > java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

[image]

Comment: Add screenshort of error message and version of cordova, nodejs, cordova-android

Comment: are you build apk right? you are getting this error when you are building apk with --release flag?

Comment: Ref https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/issues/17

Comment: @khurshid yes here is the screen shoot: https://prnt.sc/lrpl4e

Comment: Use android studio to generate signed apk .

Comment: Yes use android studio because lot of dependency and small small requirement android studio manage automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I degrade my gradle version and it works,

Comment: To what version?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when gradle tries to show you password dialog, so you can set password from your keystore in config.json as described here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#using-buildjson